# Document upload file containing a select option

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have a document upload file of multiple uploads which displays the filename and a select option where the user should select a document type for the file uploaded. The upload function works fine but there is a problem with the Select Option. Because there is a for loop on the uploaded file whenever I select an option of the doc type, the value change for all the selected doc type.

```
<input
  ref="filebtn"
  type="file"
  multiple
  @input="upload"
/>

<div
   v-for="file in files"
   :key="file.name"
>
 <div class="d-flex justify-space-between">
   <div>
     {{ file.name }}
   </div>
 </div>
 <div v-if="files.length >= 1">
   <v-select
     v-model="documentTypeModel"
     :items="documentType"
   ></v-select>
 </div>
</div>
```

And the script

```
props: {
  multiple: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
  },
},
data() {
  return {
     documentTypeModel: null,
     documentType: [
       'Item 1',
       'Item 2',
       'Item 3',
     ],
  }
},
computed: {
   filebtn: {
     cache: false,
     get() {
       return this.$refs.filebtn
     },
  },
}
methods: {
  upload() {
     const files = this.filebtn.files ?? []
      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
         if (this.multiple) {
             // eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-mutating-props
             this.files.splice(0, this.files.length)
         }
     }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use index from the loop in v-model:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
       documentTypeModel: [],
       documentType: [
         'Item 1',
         'Item 2',
         'Item 3',
       ],
       multiple: true,
       files: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
     filebtn: {
       cache: false,
       get() {
         return this.$refs.filebtn
       },
    },
  },
  methods: {
    upload() {
      this.files = [...this.filebtn.files] ?? []
      for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
        if (this.multiple) {
           this.files = this.files.splice(0, this.files.length)
        }
      }
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <input
          ref="filebtn"
          type="file"
          multiple
          @input="upload"
        />
        <div
           v-for="(file, i) in files"
           :key="file.name"
        >
         <div class="d-flex justify-space-between">
           <div>
             {{ file.name }}
           </div>
         </div>
         <v-select
           v-model="documentTypeModel[i]"
           :items="documentType"
         ></v-select>
        </div>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```